# Running Bionano´s HybridScaffolding from the command line [Error: align0.stdout]

Tags: perl

as the title says I´m trying to run [Bionanos](https://bionanogenomics.com) HybridScaffolding from the command line rather than using their own software interface. This is commercial software to primarily to identify genomewide cancer analysis but also has options for genome assembly.

I installed Perl and all the necessary packages to run the HybridScaffolding Perl script. According to their [documentation](https://bionanogenomics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/30205-Guidelines-for-Running-Bionano-Solve-Pipeline-on-Command-Line.pdf) I started the script with the correct parameters.
After 2 minutes it stops giving me the following error:

```
Beginning initial NGS CMAP to BioNano CMAP alignment...
Running command: /home/user/workflow/scripts/bionano/tools/pipeline/1.0/RefAligner/1.0/RefAligner 
-ref /home/user/results/bionano/fa2cmap/pac_bio_assembly_CTTAAG_0kb_0labels.cmap 
-i /home/user/data/bionano/bCalAnn1_Saphyr_DLE1.cmap.gz 
-o align0 -stdout -stderr -maxmem 128 -maxthreads 64 
-maxvirtmem 0 -maxmemIncrease 8 -RAmem 3 1 0.9 -M 1 3 -ScaleDelta 0.03 2 -ScaleDeltaBPP 
-hashScaleDelta 2 -res 2.6 -resSD 0.7 -FP 0.2 -FN 0.02 -sf 0.10 -sd 0.0 -sr 0.01 -se 
0.2 -extend 1 -outlier 0.0001 -endoutlier 0.001 -PVendoutlier -deltaX 12 -deltaY 12 
-xmapchim 12 -hashgen 5 11 2.4 1.4 0.05 3.0 1 1 1 -hash -hashdelta 27 -hashoffset 1 
-hashrange 0 -hashGrouped 6 11 -hashMultiMatch 50 2 -hashGC 300 -hashT2 1 -hashkeys 1 
-HSDrange 1.0 -insertThreads 4 -nosplit 2 -biaswt 0 -T 1e-10 -S -1000 -indel -PVres 2 
-rres 0.9 -outlierBC -xmapUnique 12 -AlignRes 2. -outlierExtend 12 24 -resEstimate -f 
-mres 0.9 -thetaScale 0.5 -KL 1.5 -KF 1.5 -Kmax 4 -MinFN 0.01 -MinFP 0.16 -MinSF 0.05 
-MaxSF 0.15 -MinSD 0.0 -MaxSD 0.0 -MinSR 0.007 -MaxSR 0.015 -MaxSE 0.5 -MinRes 2.0 
-MinResSD 0.7 -hashSD 0 1 -hashSR 0 1

ERROR: Cannot open align0.stdout: No such file or directory
```

For context: The HybridScaffolding script contains several scripts which are started automatically over time. One of these is the RefAligner script, which throws the error in this case.

I have a folder called align0 which lies inside the directory that the script is running, therefore I guess this is not the casual "The path is missing" issue..

Inside the Perl Script 'align0.stdout' appears two times:

```
# error check
if (errCheckRefAligner("align0.stdout", "END of output", "Initial alignment complete in $span.", "ERROR: Initial alignment cannot be completed.", 0) != 1)  {
    my $errMsg = "ERROR: Initial alignment cannot be completed.";
    printStatus(\*STATUS_FILE, "align0", $errMsg, 1);
} else  {
    printStatus(\*STATUS_FILE, "align0", "Done", 0);
} # RefAligner check
errCheckRefAligner("align0.stdout", "END of output", "Initial alignment complete in $span.", "ERROR: Initial alignment cannot be completed.", 1);
```

Sadly I don´t have any Perl knowledge at all. Does anyone have experience with Bionanos Software and/or knowledge of Perl and could explain to me what is happening inside this part of the script?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Are you sure the script can run on it? The error suggests perl is trying to open a file named `align0.stdout` for either reading or writing and that file doesn't exist. Since you are passing `align0` as an output file name with `-o align0` (I am guessing), then presumably the script will create `$outputName.stdout` somewhere. Does it work if you give a full path like `-o /home/user/data/bionano/align0`? Also, what directory are you running this from? D you have write permissions there?

Comment: I´m working on a Debian Server. I was able to spot the problem. I thought the Server had at least 256 RAM. Turns out it had only 64. I think HybridScaffolding needs at least 128 RAM. So when I ran the whole HybridScaffolding Script on a stronger Server (1000 RAM) it worked just fine without any problems :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to spot the problem. I thought the Server I was working on had at least 256 RAM. Turns out it only had 64.
I think HybridScaffolding needs at least 128 RAM. So when I ran the whole HybridScaffolding script on a stronger Server (1000 RAM) it worked just fine without any problems :)

Edit: For the record, I also had to unzip the cmap.gz file because the RefAligner could not read it zipped.